# Manage click events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have an li element and inside it I have an span. I have given click event to the li,and I want to give `click` event to the span with `move` functionality. But the click event for li also works on the span.

This is the structure:

```
<li>
    <span>::</span>
    Item 3
</li>
```

Comment: Please show your JS.

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

On span event you can use event.stopPropagation() to stop bubbled event. so it will not call parent events